# fading in and out <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade in and out some images and I used `img src=""` because it shows the full picture.  If I use a class or ID it will only show half the picture so what I'm trying to accomplish is when the user clicks on the image it will fade out that image and fade another image in.

```js
function clickimageone(l) {
  alert("test");
  question1button1 = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/firstquestion.jpg" onclick="questionone()" class="question1" style="height: 350px; width: 600px; position: absolute; top: 130px; left: 620px">
<div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone(this)" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px;  max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 650px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 780px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1500.png" onclick="clickimagethree(this)" class="border3" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 910px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/2000.png" onclick="clickimagefour(this)" class="border4" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 1040px"></div>
<img src="test.jpg" class="questiontwo" style="display:hidden;">

<Script>
  $('.border1').click(function(e) {
    $('.image, .border1, .border2, .border3, .border4, .question1, .contentanswer, .contentbackground').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('.questiontwo').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
</Script>
```

So am I able to fade in and out img tags?

Comment: No longer need help, i fixed my own problem

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer to your own question if you figured out a solution. Just a tip :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean for "full" Vs "half" picture. Screenshots might help. If you would like to leave the question here, consider editing it to make it more clear what is being asked - whether you plan on posting a solution you came up with - or otherwise. Of course, a good solution would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I simply was editing the wrong file that was why mother was happeneing